# One Point Derivations on locally Lipschitz functions

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds

Let $A$ be the algebra of $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ locally Lipschitz functions. What is the vector space of derivations at $0$? The proof that for continuous functions there aren't really any doesn't seem to work in this case.

I was thinking about trying to define the tangent spaces for Lipschitz manifolds analogously to differentiable manifolds, but I couldn't work out even this simplest example. Can tangent spaces of Lipschitz, even topological manifolds be defined at all and how?

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer in N. Weaver's book "Lipschitz algebras".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Etienne pointed out in a comment, the book [Lipschitz Algebras](http://books.google.com/books?id=45rnwyVjg_QC) by [Weaver](https://mathoverflow.net/users/23141/nik-weaver) is very much relevant. Section 4.7 introduces and describes derivations on the algebra of Lipschitz functions on a compact metric space. Weaver's constructions can be viewed as a way to introduce differentiable structures on metric spaces. See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4279) by Gong.

I don't know of any concept of a tangent space to a topological manifold. But a Lipschitz manifold is a complete doubling metric space, and therefore one can define its *tangent cones*  as (pointed) Gromov-Hausdorff limits of rescaled spaces $(X,\delta^{-1}d)$. Different sequences of scales $\delta_n$ can produce different limits, which means tangent cone is [not unique in general](https://mathoverflow.net/q/135088). See section 8.7 of [Nonsmooth Calculus](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-02/S0273-0979-07-01140-8/) by Heinonen.